# Exporting 3D Model at Runtime Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I managed to find an algorithm that uses Delaunay's Triangulation Algorithm to generate convex hulls from a set of points. So far, i've tried converting the code to Unity, all in vain. After further inspecting the code, i've noticed that the 3D Model (Procedurally Generated At Runtime via the VS C# Program) is declared as a Model3DGroup (System.windows.Media.Media3D.Model3DGroup).

Is there any way i can store this model into a 3D Model file (.fbx, .obj, .dae, etc) via code?

Comment: have you tried serialization ?

Comment: There literally is no documentation on how to do this. Even if i was able to serialize it, that wouldnt help me, as i need to convert it to .fbx, not saving the class itself

Comment: Ok you should mention that is not only to store it but that it also has to be a proprietary format. But for your solution you need to read on how to write these template format and create a streamwriter/reader class to create and read them. You will need to parse the entity of your model and generate the file according to their properties. Here a good spec sheet for the [WaveFront .obj file format](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec)

Comment: Well crap. Guess ill have to do that. And i did specify i wanted a specific file format...

Comment: For having to pass through this option in the past, know that this is a huge amount of work for a single man. You might want to look into third party 3D engine and create your 3d object then export to the format you want. Most of the time they already implement a couple of them

Comment: I guess ill just keep trying to convert to unity. Guess generating low poly rocks aint that easy :V

Comment: Obviously with tools like [Voxeland](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/9180) in the asset store, what you want is doable. You should purchase one, see what they are doing and if it doesn't suit your purpose, modify it.